# \vspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt} Effects a Shift; Is There a Better Way to Produce This Tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, tikz-pic

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\hoffset 10pt \voffset -45pt
\oddsidemargin 12pt \evensidemargin 10pt \topmargin 25pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.25in \textwidth 6.15in
\headsep 45pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}
\usepackage{pbsi}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=white,text width=0.84\textwidth,inner sep=5mm]
{ %\vspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}
{\includegraphics[width=.16\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{Berra_image.png}} \begin{minipage}{4.25in} 
\vskip -111pt 
\centerline{\LARGE{\bsifamily{\color{black} Yogi Berra Says \ldots}}}
\vspace{17pt} 
\hspace*{10pt} \fontsize{16}{17}{\textbf{``It ain't over till it's over.''}} 
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the picture

[image]

Now, running the same code with `\vspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt}` not commented out yields

[image]

It seems to me that the content within the frame of the picture has been translated somewhat.

QUESTION: Is this observation correct; if so, what is causing it? (I would think there should be no difference between the two pictures.) Is my code causing this unexpected effect? If so, how may it be improved?

Comment: you should provide a usable test file (using example-image perhaps) but `{ %`  adds an unwanted space token, `{ \vspace{0pt} \hspace{0pt} ` adds three unwanted space tokens. You probably meant `{%` which adds no space tokens.

Comment: @David Carlisle If I may, I ask what is a usable test file? Does that mean the OP uploads the image separately, and in addition to the MWE code so that the answerer may upload it without snipping? Or, does it mean to use (instead of an actual image), something like you have posted in your answer which is accessible by anybody?

Comment: @I.Yaromir best is to use one of the test images available in the tex distributions, or even not use an image at all (you could demonstrate the effect here with the image replaced by `\rule{1cm}{1cm}` for example. Failing that yes add the image to the question although it is hard to be sure it ends up the same format and size that way as imgur and stackexchange process uploaded images in somewhat unspecified ways, it is also of course then more effort for people testing the code to have to download the image and save it with the correct name.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comprehensive response.

Comment: @David Carlisle Sorry about image. I recall have seen posts that have referenced a real image in questions, as well as sometimes in the answers. I thought, perhaps, there was some cabalistic way, unbeknownst to me, that people were able to make use of  it :} Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a tikz node with a specified width is just a minipage, so you can demonstrate the effect with a much simpler reproducible test file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
}}

\fbox{\parbox{4cm}{
\hspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
}}

\end{document}
```

the `\hspace` starts a paragraph and the line ending after it then adds a word space, then you get the image.